# How can I add delete buttons to a list in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm making a clipboard history extension that stores the user's clipboard data in `localStorage`. I've finished working on the `background` so that data would be stored in the following format:

```
{list: [{text: <text that was copied>,
 date: <date when it was copied by ms>,
 current: <boolean; if the value is currently copied>]}
```

I coded `popup.html` and managed to create a list of copied items.
There is a set of buttons in each box, that can be used to delete and copy each data.

[image: Screenshot]

When the button is pressed, I need to run a function `deleteItem(ind)`, with the `ind` value set as the index of the item.

Each box is created in `forEach` by using `cloneNode`, so I do not know how many buttons there will be.

I've tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("delete")[numOfRows-1].addEventListener('click', deleteItem(numOfRows-1))
```

```
// The button element is currently not in HTML
document.getElementsByClassName("button_container")[numOfRows-1].innerHTML = "<button onclick='deleteItem(" + (numOfRows-1).toString() + ")'>Delete</button>"
```

```
document.getElementsByClassName("delete")[numOfRows-1].onClick = Function('deleteItem(" + (numOfRows-1).toString() + ")')()
```

The first one won't work because `numOfRows` keep changing as `forEach` is running, which makes it delete the wrong item.

The second one and third one won't work due to `content security policy`.

Is there a way I can add event listeners to each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all your boxes are created, run an event listener for delete and copy on each delete/copy in box, using a loop.

Example:

```js
// selects all delete buttons
var deletes = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
// loops through each delete button
for (var i = 0; i < deletes.length; i++) {
  // adds event listener to each delete button
  deletes[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // whatever you want to do when the delete button is clicked
    // Note: event.target will be the button that was clicked, do not use deletes[i]
  });
}

// same as the delete buttons, but for copying
var copies = document.querySelectorAll('.copy');
for (var i = 0; i < copies.length; i++) {
  copies[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // your code
  });
}
```

Comment: I've tried using that, but the problem is that my `deleteItem` function needs the index of the button clicked. If I put in `deleteItem(i)`, the value `i` changes as the `for` statement runs, so that the button will end up deleting the wrong item in the list when clicked.

Comment: When you create the boxes with the for loop, create the buttons in each box too. Add a custom attribute for each input with the current index of the for loop, something like `<input data-index=“{index}”>`. Then on the event listener, you can do `var index = event.target.getAttribute(‘data-value’);`. Once you have the index, you can delete the item. You will have to rebuild the boxes after every delete so that you update the index.